# I want to use php scandir in a phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, php, url, file

I want to use this in a phtml:

```
<?php 
$kataloge_dir = '../media/downloads/dlbereich/kataloge/';   
$kataloge = array_diff(scandir($kataloge_dir), array('..', '.'));

$kataloge_thumb_dir = '../media/downloads/dlbereich/kataloge-thumb/';   
$kataloge_thumb = array_diff(scandir($kataloge_thumb_dir), array('..', '.'));

$broschueren_dir = '../media/downloads/dlbereich/broschueren/'; 
$broschueren = array_diff(scandir($broschueren_dir), array('..', '.'));

$broschueren_thumb_dir = '../media/downloads/dlbereich/broschueren-thumb/'; 
$broschueren_thumb = array_diff(scandir($broschueren_thumb_dir), array('..', '.'));

$flyerlang_dir = '../media/downloads/dlbereich/flyerdinlang/';  
$flyerlang = array_diff(scandir($flyerlang_dir), array('..', '.'));

$flyerlang_thumb_dir = '../media/downloads/dlbereich/flyerdinlang-thumb/';  
$flyerlang_thumb = array_diff(scandir($flyerlang_thumb_dir), array('..', '.'));

$flyerdin4_dir = '../media/downloads/dlbereich/flyerdina4/';    
$flyerdin4 = array_diff(scandir($flyerdin4_dir), array('..', '.'));

$flyerdin4_thumb_dir = '../media/downloads/dlbereich/flyerdina4-thumb/';    
$flyerdin4_thumb = array_diff(scandir($flyerdin4_thumb_dir), array('..', '.'));

$preislisten_dir = '../media/downloads/dlbereich/preislisten/'; 
$preislisten = array_diff(scandir($preislisten_dir), array('..', '.'));

$preislisten_thumb_dir = '../media/downloads/dlbereich/preislisten-thumb/'; 
$preislisten_thumb = array_diff(scandir($preislisten_thumb_dir), array('..', '.'));

$technik_dir = '../media/downloads/dlbereich/technik/'; 
$technik = array_diff(scandir($technik_dir), array('..', '.'));

$technik_thumb_dir = '../media/downloads/dlbereich/technik-thumb/'; 
$technik_thumb = array_diff(scandir($technik_thumb_dir), array('..', '.'));

$poster_dir = '../media/downloads/dlbereich/poster/';   
$poster = array_diff(scandir($poster_dir), array('..', '.'));

$poster_thumb_dir = '../media/downloads/dlbereich/poster-thumb/';   
$poster_thumb = array_diff(scandir($poster_thumb_dir), array('..', '.'));
?>
<p><h2>Download Übersicht:</h2></p>
<button class="collapsible">Kataloge</button>
<div class="content">
<p>
<?php
foreach ($kataloge as $key => $kataloge_link)
{
    echo "<div class='boxt'>
    <div class='boxt-text'><a href='/media/downloads/dlbereich/kataloge/".$kataloge_link."'>".$kataloge_link."</a></div><div class='boxt-img'><a href='/media/downloads/dlbereich/kataloge/".$kataloge_link."'><img src='/media/downloads/dlbereich/kataloge-thumb/".$kataloge_thumb[$key]."' alt='".$kataloge_link."' /></a></div>
    </div><br>";
}
?>  
</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Broschüren</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>
    <?php
foreach ($broschueren as $key1 => $broschueren_link)
{
    echo "<div class='boxt'>
    <div class='boxt-text2'><a href='/media/downloads/dlbereich/broschueren/".$broschueren_link."'>".$broschueren_link."</a></div><div class='boxt-img2'><a href='/media/downloads/dlbereich/broschueren/".$broschueren_link."'><img src='/media/downloads/dlbereich/broschueren-thumb/".$broschueren_thumb[$key1]."' alt='".$broschueren_link."' /></a></div>
    </div><br>";
}
?>  
    </p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Flyer (DIN lang)</button>
<div class="content">
 <p>
<?php
foreach ($flyerlang as $key3 => $flyerlang_link)
{
    echo "<div class='boxt'>
    <div class='boxt-text'><a href='/media/downloads/dlbereich/flyerdinlang/".$flyerlang_link."'>".$flyerlang_link."</a></div><div class='boxt-img'><a href='/media/downloads/dlbereich/flyerdinlang/".$flyerlang_link."'><img src='/media/downloads/dlbereich/flyerdinlang-thumb/".$flyerlang_thumb[$key3]."' alt='".$flyerlang_link."' /></a></div>
    </div><br>";
}
?>      
</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Flyer (DIN A4)</button>
<div class="content">
 <p>
<?php
foreach ($flyerdin4 as $key4 => $flyerdin4_link)
{
    echo "<div class='boxt'>
    <div class='boxt-text'><a href='/media/downloads/dlbereich/flyerdina4".$flyerdin4_link."'>".$flyerdin4_link."</a></div><div class='boxt-img'><a href='/media/downloads/dlbereich/flyerdina4/".$flyerdin4_link."'><img src='/media/downloads/dlbereich/flyerdina4-thumb/".$flyerdin4_thumb[$key4]."' alt='".$flyerdin4_link."' /></a></div>
    </div><br>";
}
?>  
</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Preislisten</button>
<div class="content">
 <p>
<?php
foreach ($preislisten as $key5 => $preislisten_link)
{
    echo "<div class='boxt'>
    <div class='boxt-text'><a href='/media/downloads/dlbereich/preislisten".$preislisten_link."'>".$preislisten_link."</a></div><div class='boxt-img'><a href='/media/downloads/dlbereich/preislisten/".$preislisten_link."'><img src='/media/downloads/dlbereich/preislisten-thumb/".$preislisten_thumb[$key5]."' alt='".$preislisten_link."' /></a></div>
    </div><br>";
}
?>      
</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Technik</button>
<div class="content">
 <p>
<?php
foreach ($technik as $key6 => $technik_link)
{
    echo "<div class='boxt'>
    <div class='boxt-text'><a href='/media/downloads/dlbereich/technik".$technik_link."'>".$technik_link."</a></div><div class='boxt-img'><a href='/media/downloads/dlbereich/technik/".$technik_link."'><img src='/media/downloads/dlbereich/technik-thumb/".$technik_thumb[$key6]."' alt='".$technik_link."' /></a></div>
    </div><br>";
}
?>      
</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Poster</button>
<div class="content">
 <p>
<?php
foreach ($poster as $key7 => $poster_link)
{
    echo "<div class='boxt'>
    <div class='boxt-text'><a href='/media/downloads/dlbereich/poster".$poster_link."'>".$poster_link."</a></div><div class='boxt-img'><a href='/media/downloads/dlbereich/poster/".$poster_link."'><img src='/media/downloads/dlbereich/poster-thumb/".$poster_thumb[$key7]."' alt='".$poster_link."' /></a></div>
    </div><br>";
}
?>      
</p>
</div>
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to use it in Magento 1.9?
I get allways an Error.

Comment: What error did you get? Also where is this file being used?

Comment: If i use vardump to get info i get value NULL. I think there is a problem with scandir in Magento. The file is not in use.

Comment: instead of using relative paths, have you tried using absolute path to the directories?

Comment: Yes I tried with absolut path before. The path are OK.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to loose in a .phtml you have to create a block class and put your PHP there.

Always keep the php in template files to a minimum.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html